# Update a Model and a Collection of Models on a Single View (MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been working on an MVC 4 Application and have run into a problem when attempting to update Models in a `ViewModel`.

My `ViewModel` (detailed below) contains one `ComplexObjectOne` and a `List<ComplexObjectTwo>`.

My **GET** `ActionResult` successfully populates the `ViewModel` from a database and everything displays correctly on my `View`.

The problem is encountered when attempting to pass the `ComplexObjectOne` and `List<ComplexObjectTwo>` to the **POST** `ActionResult`.

The `ComplexObject` is passed correctly but everything I've tried fails pass the `List<ComplexObjectTwo>` collection.

My ComplexModelOne `Model`

```cs
public class Test
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Result {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<TestResult> TestResults {get;set;}
}
```

My ComplexModelTwo `Model`

```cs
public class TestResult
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Result {get;set;}
    public string Comment {get;set;}

    public virtual Test Test{get;set;}
}
```

My `ViewModel`

```cs
public class TestingViewModel
{
    public TestingViewModel()
    {
        if(TestResults == null)
        {
            TestResults = new List<TestResult>();
        }
    }

    public Test Test {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<TestResult> TestResults {get;set;}
}
```

My Edit() **GET** `ActionResult`

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        var viewModel = new TestingViewModel();

        Test test = testRepo.GetTestById(id);
        var results = test.TestResults;

        viewModel.Test = test;
        viewModel.TestResults = results;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

My Edit() **POST** `ActionResult`

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(TestingViewModel model)
{
    // do update - left out for brevity
}
```

My Edit.cshtml `View`

```cs
@model Namespace.Models.ViewModels.TestingViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test, "TestHeader")

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestResults, "TestResults")

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
}
```

Within my `View` I do use a couple of `EditorTemplates` to display the property fields.

Any assistance, comments, or suggestions will be much appreciated. I'd like to be able to accomplish updating these entities on a single page instead of multiple pages which I resorted to in the Create() steps.

Thank you,

Patrick H. (stpatrck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestResults, "TestResults")
```

with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestResults)
```

and then rename your `EditorTemplates/TestResults.cshtml` editor template to `EditorTemplates/TestResult.cshtml` (notice the missing `s`) and inside replace the model declaration from:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestResult>
```

to:

```
@model TestResult
```

Now obviously this will lead to getting rid of any `for` or `foreach` loops you might have written in this editor template because now ASP.NET MVC will automatically invoke the template for each element of the collection.

So for example:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => item.SomeProperty)
}
```

will simply become:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

Now look at the generated markup and notice the difference in the names of your input fields. Before you had:

```
<input type="text" name="item.SomeProperty" value="foo" />
```

and now you have:

```
<input type="text" name="TestResults[0].SomeProperty" value="foo" />
```

Now when you submit the form to the POST action the default model binder will be able to successfully bind the collection because now the naming convention is respected. You can read more about this convention in the [`following blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Also you have circular references in your object graph which cannot be successfully serialized and model bound. You should use view models in order to break this circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I appreciate your response and pointing out the circular references issue also. You answer solved this problem, and a couple of others, without a hitch.